# coordinates of a box in python Tkinter (3d)

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-3.6

i'm making a 3d box in python tk, but the box, when drawn in the corner screen and the window full screen, loops and creates multiple.

i'm not sure why this is happening, there should only be the one box.

Why is this creating the boxes in different locations on the canvas?

[image: tkinter window when run:]

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Game.py")
window.geometry("800x500")

canvas = Canvas(window, width = window.winfo_width(), height = window.winfo_height())
canvas.configure(background='#5d90e2')
canvas.pack()

verts = ( (-1,-1,-1), (1,-1,-1), (1,1,-1), (-1,1,-1), (-1,-1,1), (1,-1,1),(1,1,1), (-1,1,1) )

edges = (0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,0), (4,5), (5,6), (6,7), (7,4), (0,4),(1,5), (2,6), (3,7)


def fit_canvas():

    canvas.config(width= window.winfo_width(), height=window.winfo_height())

def main():

    fit_canvas()

    hw = window.winfo_width()/2
    hh = window.winfo_height()/2

    for edge in edges:

        points = []

        a = verts[edge[0]]
        b = verts[edge[1]]

        for x,y,z in  (a,b):

            z += 5
            f = int(200/z)

            x,y = x*f, y*f

            points += [(hw+x, hh+y)]

        print(points[0] , points[1])

        canvas.create_line(points[0][0],points[0][1],points[1][0],points[1}[1])


loop_no = 0

while True:
    loop_no += 1

    main()
    canvas.update()
```

Comment: This code has a syntax error so it won't run as-is. Also, your canvas has a width and height of 1 pixel, so it won't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You call `main()` in an infinite loop, so you are going to get an infinite number of boxes (until the program crashes...).

To fix the problem, remove the loop.